# How to change the App icon in a Xamarin Forms iOS App?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, icons

I want to change the Icon of my Xamarin Forms App. I already replaced all the AppIcons in the Asset catalog, but it still shows me the default Xamarin Logo. I even specified the Assetcatalog in the info.plist file, and it didn't work either. I still have this Xamarin Forms Logo and I have no ideas what to do. Any help would be nice!

Comment: clean and rebuild. if it didn't work follow this link. https://youtu.be/tbKrbv9h_ZE

Comment: It doesn't work. I set the App Icons in the Info.plist to my icons, cleaned and rebuilt my application, but it doesn't work. I used this video before.

Comment: uninstall and reinstall the app in the emulator

Comment: try in info.plist -> Visual assets tab -> put App Icons to none

Comment: I am using a physical Device. I tried to create a new App and change the icons ther but it doesn't work either.

Comment: It's also not working when set to none.

Comment: delete the App icon asset catalog then recreate it

Comment: Did it, it still shows that Xamarin Logo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241869/discussion-between-daskeksschwert3-and-amjad-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Please **check** the [limitations of Hot Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#limitations)

Asset Catalogs are currently not supported. When using Hot Restart, your app will show the default icon and launch screen for Xamarin apps. When paired to a Mac, or developing on a Mac, your Asset Catalogs will work.

If you use mac agent to deploy your application on device , the problem should be able to solved.

2.In the Info.plist file, make sure you choose the right asset source for the App Icons.

Comment: I already did that, and I dont have access to a mac. I'm using VS 2022 and have an iPhone SE.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you don't have access to a mac or a remote mac,it's not possible to change the default Xamarin icon via Asset Catalogs as this is the limitations of Hot Restart.You need a mac to get it done.